# Parsing file with recurring box of text and adding an element when it is not present

Tags: scripts, text-processing

- fruits : this is from germany, netherlands, france

  apple: ripe fruit

  orange: c vitamin

  banana: d vitamin
- fruits : this is from poland, austria

  orange: c vitamin

  pineapple: a vitamin,help in digestion: used for 2 days

  grapes: b vitamin
- fruits : this is from poland, austria

  pear: c vitamin

  apple:  ripe fruit, vitamin a, b ,c

  ```
       - white apple: {This is used for immunity boost}
  ```

  pappya: a vitamin
- fruits : this is from sweeden, norway

  orange: c vitamin

  pineapple: a vitamin

  grapes: b vitamin

---

#### Requirement:

This is a big file with more than 1000 lines. I need to add the element `apple` in fruits container **only if it is not present**, without changing the file layout structure or location of existing elements.

If something is not clear, please message me... thanks for your support in advance!

Comment: What is this “white apple” doing there?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a big file, we shall process each container individually and not load the entire file in memory. We can easily do it in Python3. Save it in `process.py` and the data in `fruits_file.txt`

```py
import sys

# This function checks if "apple" not in container then append it.
def add_apple_and_print(header, container):
    if container is not None:
        if not any(fruit.startswith("apple") for fruit in container):
            container.append('apple: ripe fruit, vitamin a, b, c')

        print("\n"+header+"\n")
        print("\n\n".join(container))

# Open the file for reading
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    header = None                         # Initialize header with None
    container = None                      # Initialize the container with None
    for line in f:                        # Read line by line
        line = line.strip()               # Remove trailing spaces
        if len(line) > 0:
            if "fruits :" in line:        # if line contains "fruits :"
                add_apple_and_print(header, container) # Print privious container
                header = line                          # Set header
                container = []                         # Create a new container for current fruit section
            else:
                container.append(line)                 # Add fruits to container

    add_apple_and_print(header, container)            # Print last container
```

then

```bsh
python3 process.py fruits_file.txt > fruits_file_with_apple.txt
```

**Edit**: In the earlier script "apple" was matching with "pineapple". Thus was not getting added in such containers. Modified the script.

Taken hints from answer by SvenMarnach on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843172/1525392)

Comment: Earlier it was made for ```python3.7+```, now it can be used with any version of ```python3```